# Erro na Central de Ajuda > Respondendo

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na [Central de Ajuda -> Respondendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) há um trecho que diz:

> A aceitação de uma resposta não é uma declaração definitiva e final indicando que a pergunta já foi respondida perfeitamente. Simplesmente significa que o autor recebeu uma resposta que funcionou para ele pessoalmente, mas nem todo usuário volta para aceitar uma resposta e aqueles que o fazem **não podem alterar a resposta aceita** se uma resposta nova e melhor surgir depois.

Isso passa a impressão que, uma vez aceita, não se pode alterar... Creio que o que se quis dizer foi:

> ... nem todo usuário volta para aceitar uma resposta, e aqueles que o fazem **podem não alterar** a resposta aceita **mesmo que** uma resposta nova e melhor surgir depois.

ou talvez:

> ... nem todo usuário volta para aceitar uma resposta **ou** aqueles que o fazem **podem alterar** a resposta aceita se uma resposta nova e melhor surgir depois.

Dependendo de qual a intenção (a primeira está mais próxima do que diz o original).

> but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

Comment: Alterado para a primeira sugestão