# Oportunismo no StackOverflow?

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas

Vejo que um determinado comportamento erróneo vem se desenvolvendo dentre os usuários do SOPT.

Dois exemplos recentes podem ser vistos nos comentários das respostas dadas às seguintes perguntas:

1. Resposta a: [Erro ao utilizar o método File.Delete dentro da Controller](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5826/3082)
2. Resposta a: [Como transformar dígitos em números por extenso em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5948/3082)

Onde se podiam ver comentários, já excluídos, do tipo:

> "-1 resposta roubada"
> "-1 por roubar do Fulano"
> "Uau, que oportunismo"

Existem muitos outros e vão variando de comentários sarcásticos ou até diretos.

---

## Significado de [Oportunismo](http://www.dicio.com.br/oportunismo/):

> Atitude daqueles que preferem contemporizar, para atingir um fim, aproveitando-se das circunstâncias oportunas.
> Sistema ou prática política, que consiste em aproveitar-se das circunstâncias ou acomodar-se a elas para tirar proveito.

Para os usuários mais experientes do StackOverflow sabem que este tipo de comportamento é errado, porém não há nenhuma regra `que diga que você não pode postar uma resposta que tenha como solução a mesma forma/meio citado em algum comentário envolvido na pergunta`. Na verdade, o usuário que está comentando provavelmente não tem tempo para elaborar uma boa resposta, e quer deixar para que outra pessoa com mais tempo faça isso, ou então simplesmente não quer por motivos próprios, ou até então por não ter certeza da solução.

Enquanto um usuário está comentando uma resposta correta, o outro pode estar pesquisando e estudando acerca da pergunta, e ocasionalmente irá postar uma resposta, e muito provavelmente contenha uma solução igual ou parecida com o comentário da resposta correta, por isso não há como afirmar que o usuário simplesmente viu o comentário da pessoa e o postou como resposta, **porém, mesmo se este fosse o caso, ele não estaria errado porém uma resposta deve estar como uma resposta, e não um comentário.**

Por isso não devemos permitir que esse comportamento se desenvolva por aqui no SOPT, pois é uma pratica totalmente errada, concordam?

Comment: Alterei um pouco a linha-temporal da pergunta para facilitar a leitura. Se por acaso perdeu o sentido que lhe querias dar, por favor, reverte a edição ou altera o que entenderes.

Comment: Ficou boa a edição @Zuul. muito obrigado :)

Comment: Faltou citar os casos em que uma pessoa cria uma pergunta e responde logo em seguida na esperança de ganhar votos positivos.

Comment: Meu caro @MayogaX qualquer pessoa pode, e é extremamente recomendada de fazer isto, tanto é que ao realizar uma pergunta você tem uma check perguntando "Responder à própria pergunta" do qual implica em responde-la antes mesmo de ela ser publicada, ou seja, você irá publicar a pergunta e a resposta ao mesmo tempo. Isso agrega conhecimento ao StackOverflow, é totalmente permitido e incentivado.

Comment: @PauloRoberto essa prática é recomendada? Não pode acabar se tornando uma forma de aproveitadores ganharem pontos? Não cheguei a reparar essa prática no SOen mas no SOpt vi um rapaz que traduziu uma pergunta do SOen e postou a resposta traduzindo também a resposta escolhida no SOen...

Comment: é recomendada sim, pois só traz benefícios à comunidade, pois da qual se obtêm conhecimento. Por isso toda prática que contribua para a comunidade e traga conhecimento é totalmente bem vinda.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Da forma como eu vejo, **todo mundo aqui está correto**.

*Dicussão encerrada então, certo?* Quem me dera.

A indignação do @AndreCalil tem base, e não se trata apenas de querer os ***deliciosos pontos de internet que valem mais do que dinheiro*** (*Foi mal pessoal de Portugal que não vai entender a referência*). Reconhecimento a quem apontou/construiu a resposta correta é também uma questão de dar *crédito* a quem merece. É uma forma de justiça, mesmo que não haja reputação envolvida.

Todo mundo gosta de justiça (*principalmente as pessoas maravilhosas que frequentam o SOPT, **certo?***) e ver a pessoa que realizou um bom trabalho ter o merecido destaque é excelente e faz todo mundo se sentir bem. Portanto, se revoltar com quem quer tirar crédito dos outros é uma reação natural.

## A Navalha de Hanlon

Isso **não** quer dizer que se aparecerem duas ou mais respostas iguais, ou uma resposta após um comentário, o post mais novo é automaticamente culpado de fraude. Como o @mgibisonbr bem lembrou, a [Navalha de Hanlon](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navalha_de_Hanlon) é perfeitamente cabível nesse caso:

> **Nunca atribua à malícia o que pode ser adequadamente explicado pela estupidez**
>
> > **ATENÇÃO:** A frase não é do [Jay Hanlon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14/jaydles), mas ele gosta de fingir que é.
> > **ATENÇÃO 2:** Nem eu, nem o Jay, estamos chamando ninguém de estúpido por postar uma resposta igual a outra existente.

A filosofia por trás disso é que ver dois posts iguais não implica que um deles é copiado do outro. Duas (ou mais) pessoas podem chegar à mesma solução sem nunca terem conversado uma com a outra, e ninguém é obrigado a ler toda uma discussão só para se certificar de que um conteúdo não vai ser repetido.

Um efeito indireto de deixar as respostas mais votadas (e a aceita) no topo é que ela quase nunca é inadvertidamente copiada, porque é bem óbvio que ela foi feita. Ainda assim, alguém pode decidir simplesmente escrever uma resposta *melhor* do que a que está no topo, usando a mesma fundamentação. Talvez dando exemplos melhores, ou citando referências mais profundas, ou simplesmente escrevendo uma resposta mais completa. Nada disso seria encaixado na categoria de plágio.

No caso das perguntas em questão, tudo que temos são os horários das atividades e eles dizem rigorosamente nada de concreto. São apenas circunstanciais e não servem de embasamento para sustentar que alguém agiu de forma incorreta.

## Então o que fazer?

Depende... Se você vir um comentário que deveria ser uma resposta, o [post no MSOEN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221502/unanswered-questions-which-were-answered-in-the-comments) que o @AndreCalil referenciou é provavelmente o melhor caminho (se alguém tiver uma metodologia melhor, pode falar):

> No caso de comentários que resolvem a pergunta, a coisa mais educada a se fazer é notificar o autor do comentário com um outro comentário (@Usuário), pedindo para que o comentário seja reescrito como resposta.
>
> Se o usuário escrever a resposta, ótimo! Recompense o trabalho com um voto e aceite a resposta como correta.
>
> Se, depois de um período razoável, o autor do comentário não agir, crie você mesmo uma resposta com a solução, citando o comentário como fonte.

É um bom método. Dá chance ao autor do comentário de conseguir o crédito que ele merece mas mantém um bom plano B, que beneficia ao site com uma resposta correta e ao autor do comentário com o crédito pelo que descobriu.

Para o caso se deparar com duas respostas iguais, ou uma resposta similar a um comentário, há muito pouco que se possa fazer. Não se pode presumir alguém como culpado. Uma coincidência é perfeitamente plausível, e avaliar o horário das postagens diz muito pouco.

Mas claro, existem exceções. Se a resposta mais nova contiver trechos exatos do comentário (ou reposta anterior), dando a entender que ela foi **copiada diretamente**, uma flag talvez seja necessária e outras atitudes podem ser tomadas. Mas esse é um comportamento que deve ser utilizado em raros casos em que isso se comprove.

Comment: Gabe, obrigado pela participação. Acho sua ponderação cabível e fico feliz que você tenha concordado com a sugestão que trouxe do MSOEN. Podemos adotar isso como conduta, afinal?

Comment: @AndreCalil Eu acredito que sim. Lembrando que isso vale como uma regra "pessoal", já que não temos como garantir que os outros vão agir (ou deixaram de agir) dessa forma.

Comment: Exato. Como eu previ em um dos comentários na minha resposta (não vá lá, vc não vai gostar), o que temos desta discussão é apenas uma *recomendação de comportamento*.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, porém to achando que essa discussão meio que tomou outro rumo, sendo que eu queria focar um pouco mais nas pessoas que estavam sendo "acusadas" de `roubo` ou de estar sendo `oportunista` por apenas terem postado a resposta igual ao comentário `"sem querer"` porque não viu o comentário. Porém se a pessoa viu o comentário e mesmo assim postou, sem deixar um tempo pro cara postar, aí sim concordo com vocês :)

Comment: Prezados, posso ter feito "leitura dinâmica" mas acho que vale um ponto fundamental que parece esquecido por aqui: sempre que você "chupa resposta" de terceiros, não importa se do ambiente Stack ou de outros sites, é importante DAR CRÉDITO CITANDO A FONTE. Sem citar, é plágio, é "roubo". A redação científica ([artigos científicos](http://www.nature.com/)) é chata por ser repleta de citações, mas é necessário... Até [a Wikipedia exige citações](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Livro_de_estilo/Cite_as_fontes).

Comment: Eu estava repensando aqui depois de um longo tempo... será que não seria possível o StackOverflow implementar algo que identifique quando o usuário realiza um `Ctrl + C`(copy) em um comentário de uma pessoa, ou então quando ele clica em um link do comentário? aí automaticamente o Stack colocaria fonte do usuario tal via copy and paste ou via link shared. Algo do tipo?

Answer (score 16):

O StackOverflow é um site de perguntas e respostas, não um show de auditório onde quem aperta primeiro o botão ganha os pontos. É perfeitamente aceitável uma resposta conter conteúdo idêntico a de outra resposta ou de um comentário.

Dito isso, há dois pontos a serem considerados:

1. [Atribuição da fonte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319/215): se sua resposta possui uma fonte externa primária (i.e. não advém simplesmente do seu próprio conhecimento), então é importante - e muitas vezes necessário - citar corretamente a fonte. Quando se trata de uma "descoberta independente", então não é necessário que uma resposta mencione a outra, mas se um respondente está ciente do conteúdo do outro **antes de postar**, é desejável [por cortesia] uma menção - mas não é obrigatório. Se por outro lado o comentário do outro foi a fonte primária da sua resposta, então a citação deveria ser mandatória.

   - Ex.: como apontado por fulano nos comentários, seu problema é blá bla blá.
2. Quem aceita uma resposta não tem obrigação de aceitar aquela que veio primeiro. Se uma resposta simples veio antes, outra mais elaborada depois, cada um tem direito de votar naquela(s) que considera mais úteis/completas/corretas, e quem aceita tem direito de escolher aquela que considerou mais satisfatória.

   Se o autor da pergunta **optou** por aceitar a resposta que veio primeiro - mesmo que isso signifique desmarcar uma resposta aceita anteriormente para marcar a outra - isso é direito dele. Não é uma obrigação (ele pode adotar os critérios que achar melhor), mas é um direito.

Por fim, gostaria de citar a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (ênfase minha):

> Aceitar uma resposta **não é obrigatório**; **não se sinta obrigado a aceitar a primeira resposta que você receber**. Espere até receber uma resposta que responda bem à sua pergunta.

E em [uma outra parte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> A aceitação de uma resposta não é uma declaração definitiva e final indicando que a pergunta já foi respondida perfeitamente. Simplesmente significa que o autor recebeu uma resposta que funcionou para ele pessoalmente, mas nem todo usuário volta para aceitar uma resposta e **aqueles que o fazem não podem alterar a resposta aceita [sic] se uma resposta nova e melhor surgir depois**.

(Nota: o erro na tradução do trecho acima [já foi reportado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/651/215) - "e aqueles que o fazem **podem não alterar** a resposta aceita..." ou "**ou** aqueles que o fazem **podem alterar** a resposta aceita...")

Comment: Até porque perguntas podem ser mal formuladas, tipo alguém pergunta algo como: "*Como inserir um texto em um input quando ele estiver vazio e remover o texto quando o usuário escrever algo?*" para alguns um `placeholder` é a solução, mas outros chegam à pergunta tempos depois simplesmente pois não querem usar esta propriedade, então a mesma pergunta pode agradar aos 2 públicos, o importante é que o problema consiga ser resolvido.

Comment: exatamente @mgibsonbr, é bem isso mesmo, só que o pessoal tá levando isso de maneira errada.

Comment: Acho que vocês divagaram um pouco. A questão aqui não está relacionada com a qualidade da pergunta, é uma questão de comportamento.

Comment: Você quis dizer `qualidade da resposta` não é? Acho que você que não está associando uma coisa com a outra, que no caso deveria.

Comment: @PauloRoberto `Até porque perguntas podem ser mal formuladas`. Qualidade da pergunta, sim.

Comment: Ah, sim, porém muito que indiretamente até isso pode influenciar um pouco, pois podem haver dois entendimentos diferentes que chegaram na mesma resposta, por exemplo.

Comment: Isso *pode* acontecer, sem duvida. Porem, possivelmente seriam duas respostas diferentes (dois entendimentos da pergunta). De qualquer forma, nao e a questao que estamos discutindo aqui.

Answer (score 16):

Eu vejo pontos válidos em todas as opiniões publicadas aqui até agora, mas quero enfatizar algo que ninguém disse e acho importante.

O debate está polarizado entre dois usuários que pensam a mesma coisa: "eu estou certo, e você está errado". E ambos estão se esquecendo de uma das diretrizes fundamentais da rede Stack Exchange, presente na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> **Seja simpático.**
>
> É necessário ter civilidade sempre; grosserias não serão toleradas. Trate os outros com o mesmo respeito que deseja ser tratado porque todos estamos aqui para aprender, juntos. Seja tolerante com os que não sabem tudo o que você sabe e tenha senso de humor.

Na minha opinião, o @PauloRoberto poderia ter deixado um comentário para o @LuizVieira, dizendo que postou uma resposta baseada no código que ele indicou como link. Mesmo que ele tenha chegado ao mesmo link de maneira independente, seria simpático deixar um comentário assim. O @AndreCalil, por sua vez, pegou pesado ao acusar o @PauloHDSousa sem maiores informações. Não se acusa sem provas.

Dito isto, não acho que haja regras que permitam lidar com esse tipo de situação de maneira genérica. Eu pessoalmente costumo levar em conta o seguinte:

- Se usei em minha resposta algo de outra resposta ou comentário, eu cito a fonte.
- Se faltam informações na pergunta e um comentário indica uma possível resposta, eu aguardo esclarecimentos do autor, pois nada garante que aquela resposta é mesmo a resposta.
- Se vejo um comentário pedindo esclarecimentos, costumo dar um tempo se o autor do comentário não vai adicionar uma resposta. Muitas vezes sugiro a ele que faça isso. E às vezes a resposta é "não quero, se quiser vá em frente".
- O fato de uma resposta usar uma solução que consta de um comentário não quer dizer nada por si só. Comentários são efêmeros, e respostas de verdade precisam ser postadas como respostas. Além disso, dificilmente uma resposta completa cabe em um comentário.
- Se outro usuário me acusa ou provoca nos comentários, posso até rebater, mas não levo a discussão adiante se percebo que ela vai se estender. Se achar necessário, posto algo no meta, caso contrário simplesmente ignoro o outro usuário por considerar que a discussão não será produtiva (nenhum dos dois parece disposto a ceder em ponto algum). Se algum comentário me ofende, ou a outra pessoa, sinalizo para atenção dos moderadores.

Comment: Só queria entender qual foi a acusação. De oportunista? Falei sem preocupação porque não acho que *oportunista* seja uma acusação depreciativa. Alguém aqui comentou `mas ser oportunista não é errado`, e não é mesmo. Vou insistir: até adicionei um smile para dar tom ao comentário e justamente evitar problemas da comunicação escrita.

Comment: @AndreCalil A leitura que fiz do comentário não foi bem essa, parecia sarcástico. De fato é complicado transmitir certas coisas por escrito, mesmo com emoticons. Eu achei o comentário questionável, e o Paulo Roberto mais ainda, por ter passado por algo semelhante recentemente.

Comment: Eu entendo que o Paulo tenha vindo da outra questão (onde utilizaram o termo *roubado*, muito mais agressivo) com esse humor, por isso tenha lido o meu comentário com outro tom. De qualquer forma, as palavras utilizadas e o emoticon deixam bem claro que eu não estava dando bash em ninguém.

Comment: @AndreCalil Meu ponto no comentário anterior é que *não estava tão claro assim*. Oportunismo é um termo com conotações boas e ruins, e não acho que um `:)` seja suficiente para desfazer a ambiguidade.

Comment: Concordo contigo, porém eu nem tinha sequer visto o comentário do @LuizVieira quando postei a resposta...

Comment: @AndreCalil não podemos usar palavras que podem ter conotações ruins em uma comunidade tão ampla, com tantas pessoas de lugares diferentes, culturas diferentes, onde você não sabe o que a pessoa está pensando/pelo que está passando no momento que leu o comentário, por isso temos que tomar extrema cautela com o que falamos, para que de nenhuma maneira alguém possa se sentir ofendido. Exemplo: quando eu falei de um certo grupo de pessoas, porém utilizei termo: `"eles são só pra rir"` quis dizer divertidos, mas não posso ter certeza que eles irão entender, por isso retirei minha mensagem no chat.

Comment: @PauloRoberto eu concordo contigo e estou começando a considerar que talvez meu comentário pudesse ter sido repensado. Ainda assim, ele ficou muito longe dos que você recebeu na sua resposta. E, insisto no que falei antes: o Paulo Sousa não chegou nem perto de se ofender, quem tomou as dores e ficou magoado foi você. Daí eu realmente não sei como agir: A e B se entendem, C sai ofendido. Sinceramente não acho que tenha sido para tanto.

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 Falou E disse. :)

Answer (score 12):

Para mim se o objetivo geral foi alcançado (ajudar o questionador a solucionar o seu problema), tanto faz quem teve a resposta marcada como correta ou quem teve mais *upvotes*.

Essa disputa por *upvotes* para ser agora que algumas pessoas não entendem o objetivo da comunidade, pessoas que nunca fizeram o uso correto da versão em inglês e procuravam apenas por código pra copiar e colar.

Concordo que eu mesmo ainda não faço o uso da comunidade de forma perfeita, mas eu tento aceitar as críticas que vem à mim e corrigir, sempre com o objetivo de melhorar a comunidade e a qualidade das perguntas e respostas.

Eu costumo chamar isso de "garimpar reputação" porque são pessoas que só querem dizer depois "tenho 1000 a mais de reputação que você", como se fosse mais importante os números que o objetivo geral. Se essa disputa for saudável para a comunidade eu não vejo problemas, mas quando a disputa se torna o foco e não ajudar a quem realmente tem dúvidas, aí isso é muito destrutivo.

Comment: exatamente, não sei se você viu mas estavam discutindo comigo falando da forma "eu tenho mais pontos de rep no SO EN sabia?"

Comment: Eu vi sim o comentário em questão. Isso acaba se tornando disputa de ego e não trabalho distribuído.

Answer (score 3):

Bem, eu postei a resposta sem olhar no comentário porque já havia passado por algo semelhante... de qualquer modo se eu prejudiquei alguém peço desculpas.

Comment: Como o mais "ofendido" desta história seria eu, repito: não há do que se desculpar. Primeiro porque ainda não terminamos o assunto e é possível que você tenha agido corretamente, segundo porque, de qualquer forma, não houve ofensas. Fique tranquilo :)

Comment: Você, com certeza, não prejudicou ninguém @PauloHDSousa, muito pelo contrário, você ajudou a comunidade postando uma resposta para a pergunta em questão, nada além disto.

Answer (score 0):

Como a maioria dos casos de comportamento no SO, vamos analisar cada situação sem criar uma regra geral, por enquanto:

[Primeiro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5798/erro-ao-utilizar-o-metodo-file-delete-dentro-da-controller/5826#5826):

- **2014-02-14 12:19**: Pergunta
- **2014-02-14 12:31**: Comentário com resposta correta
- **2014-02-14 12:33**: Confirmação do OP
- **2014-02-14 12:36**: Sugestão para incluir como resposta
- **2014-02-14 13:21**: Resposta idêntica adicionada por outro usuário

[Segundo exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5945/como-transformar-digitos-em-numeros-por-extenso-em-javascript/5948#5948):

- **2014-02-15 00:37**: Pergunta
- **2014-02-15 00:44**: Comentário com resposta correta
- **2014-02-15 00:57**: Confirmação do OP e sugestão para incluir como resposta
- **2014-02-15 01:00**: Resposta idêntica adicionada por outro usuário (o código JS está no link do comentário)

Uma coisa é o usuário pensar "vou ajudar a comunidade" e incluir a resposta para que uma pergunta não fique pendente por dias sendo que a informação já está ali. Outra *bem diferente* é, em questão de minutos, escrever uma resposta idêntica ao comentário já aceito.

Até porque, para todos os casos, a comunidade já foi beneficiada. A informação está disponível, em o sistema de comentários é parte importante da engine do SE. Haja visto que comentários bem votados recebem destaque.

Na falta de referências (ainda) no nosso meta, veja [esta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221502/unanswered-questions-which-were-answered-in-the-comments) no meta do SOEN. Não se trata de "haver uma regra" para impedir este comportamento, mas sim de ética. Não é só porque não há uma regra impedindo que isso seja legal, certo? Pense na sua convivência em sociedade. Há *muitas* coisas que a lei não proíbe e que nem por isso você sai fazendo.

Um colega comentou sobre "garimpeiros de reputação" (o SOEN tem uma expressão mais grosseira para isso...). Neste caso, quem está garimpando reputação: o usuário que forneceu a resposta correta e quer apenas justiça com o seu conhecimento ou o segundo usuário, que aproveitou-se da *oportunidade* (daí *oportunista*) para postar a resposta de outro sem ao menos prestar a devida referência?

---

**Update**

Depois de uma extensa discussão nos comentários, vou expressar novamente minha opinião. Em resumo: **acho errado um usuário postar uma resposta idêntica a um comentário que tenha sido confirmado**. De qualquer forma, para evitar que a pergunta fique pendente, vale adicionar a resposta e dar o crédito ao usuário original. Algo do tipo "Segundo o comentário do @Fulano, (...)". Ou, melhor ainda: "@Fulano sugeriu isso, mas acho que podemos ir além, veja: (...)". Vejam que lindo! Você dá o crédito ao usuário que iniciou a solução e a complementa com o seu conhecimento.

> Mas isso não é proibido.

Não, assim como subir na mesa da sua sogra na hora do almoço e dançar o kuduro também não é. Mas você não vai fazer isso. Por que? Porque tem bom senso, respeito aos que estão ali, consideração à sua/seu companheira(o).

> Mas por que a pessoa vai fazer isso? Você está só *garimpando reputação*.

Não, não estou. Quem acompanhou a conversação na minha questão original viu que em nenhum momento eu cobrei que minha resposta fosse pontuada. Depois que o OP se manifestou e o usuário que respondeu expressou preocupação foi que eu adicionei minha resposta. Até então, tudo que fiz foi comentar *com um smile* a resposta original.
Da mesma forma, minha primeira resposta aqui não fala em reputação. Vejam o link que trouxe do mSE, lá mesmo a resposta sugere apenas que seja feita a referência ao usuário original.

Por que isso? **Por respeito, consideração, ética, bom senso**. Porque algum usuário foi mais rápido, teve mais conhecimento do que você *ou* te deu uma luz para melhorar sua resposta. Isso é política da boa vizinhança, **trabalho em equipe**, não briga por reputação.

Comment: -1, Discordo: `"o segundo usuário, que aproveitou-se da oportunidade (daí oportunista) para postar a resposta de outro sem ao menos prestar a devida referência?"` De qual referência você tá falando? como você pode ter certeza que ele teve como referência o comentário ao invés de uma pesquisa no Google?

Comment: Lidar com ética, ainda mais em um ambiente de pessoas tão distintas em todos os sentidos, é uma coisa extremamente complicada. Se nos focarmos em um ambiente pequeno já é complicado, em um ambiente tão amplo como esse então, é mais complicado ainda. Então acusar alguém de falta de ética por postar uma resposta, principalmente sem ter completa certeza dos objetivos dessa pessoa, é algo muito grave.

Comment: Serio, eu só tentei ajudar quando coloquei a respostas porque eu já passei por esse problema (Exemplo nº 1). Eu tenho um blog que eu ensino algumas coisas com frequência, sou ativo também no fórum MSDN, não tive intenção de prejudicar ninguém. desculpa qualquer coisa.

Comment: E outra coisa, porque aproveitar uma oportunidade é tão ruim? Cumpriu o objetivo de ajudar ao questionador? Caso sim não vejo problema nenhum em aproveitar uma `oportunidade`, desde que seja feito com uma resposta de qualidade e focada no questionador.

Comment: @ErlonCharles não acusei ninguém de ser antiético, mas falei que trata-se de uma questão de ética, porque o Paulo insistiu em repetir que não há uma regra para isso. Ser oportunista não é sempre ruim, de fato, mas nestes casos a oportunidade é sobre outro usuário, por isso acho impróprio.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa ficou claro que não foi por mal, até porque você voltou atrás. De qualquer forma, foi importante para trazer este assunto.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Na minha opinião, esse é o X da questão: não dá pra **provar** que o outro usuário *sequer leu* os comentários, mas as circunstâncias sugerem que sim. É uma questão de "assumir ignorância antes de malícia". No mais, um trecho de código pequeno o suficiente sofre de "limitação de forma alternativa para sua expressão" (expressão tirada da própria [lei do software](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm)).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Certo, daí cabe a atitude do Paulo Sousa: comenta para o OP, retira sua resposta. Afinal, foi falha dele não ter lido a questão inteira (incluindo os comentários).

Comment: Quando se menciona ética, você precisa ter algum embasamento pra isso, se não vai soar como uma acusação. Quando você não diz explicitamente a ocasião da falta de ética, parece que alguém roubou algo que era seu, ou publicou uma ideia sua sem sua permissão. Estou falando deste trecho "*Não se trata de "haver uma regra" para impedir este comportamento, mas sim de ética.*"

Comment: @ErlonCharles Exato, foi isso que eu disse no comentário. Paulo Roberto insiste que "pode porque não há regra impedindo" (resumi, mas a ideia é esta). Eu insisto que "não pode por ética".

Comment: @AndreCalil Porque você acha que a atitude do Paulo Sousa deveria ser esta? eu discordo, porque você não está `"reservando seu lugar"` ao comentar uma resposta correta, por isso nada impede de alguém postar outra resposta, e também não considero a ação anti-ética.

Comment: @AndreCalil quem define esses parâmetros de ética?

Comment: @PauloRoberto veja a timeline dos fatos da pergunta, isso justifica minha opinião. Por mais que tenha postado a resposta sem ver o comentário, seguiu como eu acho apropriado.

Comment: @AndreCalil Sinto muito, mas esta é sua opinião meu caro, pode não ser a do resto.

Comment: @PauloRoberto sem problemas, é por isso que estamos discutindo esta questão aqui no meta.

Comment: Então aqui é só debate ou dependendo da situação o SO pode adicionar regras e funcionalidades no SO?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa É muito improvável que saia uma *funcionalidade* daqui. O mais certo é que tenhamos uma *recomendação de comportamento* ao fim da discussão.

Comment: Quem sabe uma flag: comentário marcado como `insinuando oportunismo`

Comment: @PauloRoberto acho uma boa saída. Talvez `propriedade de outro usuário`

Comment: **Realmente não foi isso que eu quis dizer**, na verdade era **ao contrário**, porque nenhum usuário possui direitos autorais de nenhuma resposta aqui postada, pois elas são postadas realmente para serem usadas. Você não tem que esperar nada em troca ao responder uma pergunta, você faz apenas para ajudar. Eu quis dizer marcar um comentário como `"o comentário está insinuando que o autor da resposta copiou de alguém"` ou seja `"Insinuando oportunismo"`

Comment: @AndreCalil se você acha que foi **injustiçado** e deseja que o Paulo **retire a resposta dele** para que **você fique com os pontos**, então você é um garimpeiro de pontos, e é o seu comportamento que não é benéfico aqui. Meus upvotes vão para o Paulo.

Comment: @Renan no mesmo sentido, se eu fiz um comentário que foi aproveitado por outro usuário para conseguir pontos sem me dar tempo suficiente para postar a resposta, quem está garimpando pontos é ele. Você está deixando de notar que linkei uma pergunta do meta SOEN onde a resposta menciona ao menos "dar crédito". A questão aqui não é receber os pontos, mas o crédito/reconhecimento.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Tecnicamente, quem posta aqui é detentor de todos os direitos autorais sobre o conteúdo postado. Apenas disponibiliza o mesmo via CC-BY-SA. Por isso a correta citação de fonte é sim **mandatória**. O que eu questiono é se um comentário curto, onde **faltam meios alternativos pra sua expressão** se enquadra nesse caso ou não (e minha opinião *pessoal* é **não** - a resposta em questão não constitui cópia ou plágio).

Comment: Vejo que este é um tema controverso. Gostaria mto de ouvir a opinião do @Gabe.

Comment: concordo @mgibsonbr tenho o mesmo ponto de vista, desculpe-me se me expressei mal na frase.

Comment: @AndreCalil ele ter postado antes não impede você de postar sua resposta, muito menos de identificar pontos em que a resposta dele foi incompleta e completa-la na sua resposta. Acredito que se o foco for responder à pergunta do questionador da melhor forma não há nada de prejudicial nisso, pelo contrário, faz parte da dinâmica.

Comment: @ErlonCharles o ponto é consideração, reconhecimento, respeito. Ele postou uma resposta idêntica ao meio comentário logo depois de ele ter sido confirmado. Se tivesse incluindo uma menção do tipo "Segundo sugestão do [at]Fulano no comentário, (...)". Veja o link que trouxe do meta SOEN, é exatamente isso. Eu não falei em reputação, foi a discussão aqui nos comentários que trouxe isso. E sim, a resposta do OP foi respondida, então acho que está tudo certo. Volto ao meu primeiro ponto: é apenas uma questão de ética.

Comment: Então mudamos o foco de **ética** para **reconhecimento** e **respeito**. Agora sua reclamação faz mais sentido.

Comment: @ErlonCharles que seja. Sei que são assuntos diferentes, mas os relaciono porque acho que estão totalmente interligados aqui. Não há uma regra que obrigue o usuário a fazer isso, mas há (deveria haver) o bom senso, a ética na comunidade, o respeito ao colega que - se não possuía mais conhecimento (nos casos de *COINCIDÊNCIA* mesmo) - foi mais rápido.

Comment: Acredito que até para promover uma boa convivência você poderia apenas fazer uma recomendação para que isso não ocorra mais, em alguns pontos você foi bem taxativo e agressivo e isso é pior que ser um mal oportunista. (até aproveitando a resposta do @bfavaretto hehe)

Comment: @ErlonCharles você me inspirou a atualizar minha resposta.