# Solução obtida em comentários

Tags: debate, perguntas, comentários

Eis a pergunta: [Não redimensionar imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20602/nao-redimensionar-imagem)

Como fica a resposta nesse caso em que o problema foi solucionado nos comentários? Devo adicionar uma resposta, sinalizar?

quais os passos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No caso de comentários que resolvem a pergunta, a coisa mais educada a se fazer é notificar o autor do comentário com um outro comentário (@Usuário), pedindo para que o comentário seja reescrito como resposta.

Se o usuário escrever a resposta, ótimo! Recompense o trabalho com um voto e aceite a resposta como correta.

Se, depois de um período razoável, o autor do comentário não agir, crie você mesmo uma resposta com a solução, citando o comentário como fonte.

[Fonte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/899/215). [Fonte da fonte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54945/177950) (MSE, em inglês).

Comment: ok, no caso o autor da resposta sou eu mesmo hehe

Comment: Caso esteja a postar uma resposta que não seja sua, pode, ***opcionalmente***, marcar a resposta como "wiki da comunidade" para [abdicar da pontuação e da propriedade do conteúdo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1476/429).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal esse seu comment está no limiar do caso, ele é praticamente uma resposta :)