# Como lidar com respostas muito similares ou idênticas

Tags: debate

[Nesta resposta, mgibsonbr diz que: "É perfeitamente aceitável uma resposta conter conteúdo idêntico a de outra resposta ou de um comentário".](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/893/5010)

Isso é algo que ainda me deixa com dúvidas. É mesmo perfeitamente aceitável?

Por exemplo, se alguém responde:

> Tente `1+(2+3)`

E outras duas pessoas, muitos minutos depois,  colocam respostas do tipo:

> Você também pode tentar `(1+2)+3`.
>
> É possível resolver com `1+2+3`.

Como lidar com a situação? Fatores como o tempo de postagem deveiram mudar a forma de lidar com isso? Que outros fatores devem ser levados em conta?

Comment: Qual a diferença de *timing* na postagem? Tem algum exemplo concreto?

Comment: @brasofilo tenho vários, muitos do SOen, mas queria fazer uma discussão mais geral sobre o tema, e não sobre casos concretos.

Comment: Se eu fosse responder, ia diferenciar entre "postagens paralelas" e "postagens distanciadas". No primeiro caso, nada a fazer, e no segundo seguindo a escala: comentar, negativar, sinalizar como low quality, votar pra deletar.

Comment: [Um exemplo concreto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34780/3117)

Comment: Casos do SOen devem ser discutidos lá, nós não seguimos os mesmos critérios deles. Eu acho esse exemplo do @Math um caso ruim por si só, deveria converter para comentário. Eu acho difícil neste caso falar muito diferente do que o mgibsonbr na resposta citada. Em casos específicos eu acho que pode haver algo que torna a resposta forçada. Mesmo assim, em geral não dá para fazer muita coisa. Mesmo uma negativação pode ser exagerada. Perguntar o que aquela resposta acrescentou ao que já existe poderia ser uma boa.

Comment: Se a pergunta é muito popular (por exemplo, perguntas com muitos votos, com recompensa, ou mesmo com muitas respostas) pode acontecer sim de um usuário responder algo repetido sem nem mesmo ler o que já foi escrito antes (em comentário e/ou resposta). Esse é o típico cenário "me too" que é a razão de existir da [**função proteger**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Entretanto, não sei responder quando exatamente essa função deva ser usada, nem o que fazer com as respostas que já estão lá... Quando ao caso de mera similaridade, vou postar uma resposta em breve.

Comment: valeu @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 4):

Duas postagens podem se assemelhar tanto em **forma** como em **conteúdo**. Exceto pelos casos em que *ambas* são semelhantes - o que pode caracterizar plágio, muito embora eu não me arriscaria a tentar definir os limites do que é ou não plágio - reafirmo que não vejo problema em se ter respostas parecidas.

Às vezes a forma é semelhante mas o conteúdo não. Calcular `(1+2)+3` é diferente na prática de calcular `1+(2+3)`, e o uso de `1+2+3` tem impacto na concisão e na clareza da solução. Dar uma resposta dessas sendo que outra já está presente deveria idealmente vir acompanhada de uma explicação do porquê da diferença (tipo: `(a*b)/c` pode dar overflow, mas `a*(b/c)` pode ter erro de arredondamento). Se o usuário simplesmente falou "faça isso" e não justificou, pode-se considerar que falta *qualidade* na sua resposta, inclusive é bom comentar perguntando "o que essa resposta tem de diferente daquela já apresentada por fulano?". Se o autor não se pronunciar de forma satisfatória, cabe um *no-vote* ou *downvote*... (i.e. pessoalmente, não vejo razão pra ir além disso)

Em outros casos, o conteúdo é o mesmo mas a forma é diferente. Eu próprio, 90% das vezes que eu decido responder uma pergunta sendo que já existe outra resposta correta anterior à minha, é porque eu não gostei da forma de apresentação da mesma. Ou até gostei, mas quis dar uma ênfase diferente. Em geral não me preocupo com o intervalo de tempo entre as respostas nessas situações. Nesse caso, é um pouco mais difícil de julgar se a resposta "acrescenta alguma coisa" ou não: eu posso ter achado que minha forma de apresentar é mais clara, concisa, completa, etc, mas outros podem achar que ela só repete o que já foi dito. Como determinar isso objetivamente? Difícil... Por essa razão, creio que a resposta da comunidade deve ser a mesma do caso anterior: usar o voto pra classificar a qualidade da resposta, e só.

---

Por fim, um comentário sobre a resposta linkada: [na outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/890/215), a preocupação central era em "premiar quem chegou primeiro à resposta". O que a princípio parece justo, mas na prática acaba encorajando ["o gatilho mais rápido do oeste"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/177950): se eu começo a escrever uma resposta média/longa - com texto claro, exemplo de código comentado, links pra documentação, exemplo executável, etc - e nesse meio tempo alguém joga nos comentários "tente a função X", é justo dar todo o crédito a essa pessoa só porque "foi ela quem trouxe esse conhecimento pra comunidade"? Em particular se for algo de conhecimento comum? É o tipo de situação estressante, pois você quer concluir satisfatoriamente sua resposta, mas você vê a discussão correndo nos comentários e percebe que se não clicar em "submeter" logo a pergunta será abandonada e pronto (sem resposta, ou talvez com uma resposta simples rapidamente aceita).

Quando a resposta é suficientemente longa, dá pra qualquer um [com bom senso] perceber que você já estava escrevendo aquela resposta há mais tempo. Mas quando a resposta é só *densa* (ex.: eu não me contentei em dizer pra usar a função X, eu procurei um link pra documentação *em português* da função X para acrescentar à resposta) isso não fica tão óbvio, levando alguns a pensar que você agiu de forma "oportunista", se apropriando da resposta de outra pessoa.

Foi nesse contexto que fiz a afirmação acima, não no sentido de fazer "apologia ao plágio" ou nada parecido (muito embora eu admita que, ideologicamente falando, eu seja bastante radical na minha oposição a patentes e *copyrights* - sendo bem mais tolerante à cópia de conteúdo de terceiros do que a maioria das pessoas consideraria correto). Mas de fato, "perfeitamente aceitável" é uma expressão forte demais para se aplicar a um caso genérico, abstrato, envolvendo "conteúdo idêntico".

Comment: Muito boa sua exposição!

Comment: +1 por expressar muito bem como é passar por uma situação estressante de se estar escrevendo uma resposta com qualidade e ser ofuscado por uma resposta sem qualidade (ou comentário) que foi mais rápida que a sua

Comment: Pior é quando as pessoas não entendem a pergunta, e estão votando pra fechar - se você não submeter a resposta logo, nem poderá mais fazê-lo... :P (passei por isso algumas vezes no SOen)

Comment: A questão do "gatilho mais rápido do oeste" é uma faca de 2 gumes.. às vezes, o AP precisa de agilidade ou a resposta é simples; mas outras, uma boa resposta ou uma resposta correta pode aparecer depois de somente um certo tempo, o que acaba por dar piores respostas como mais votadas e até aceitas. Simplesmente pq surgiram antes. Uma solução parcial seria o Autor da Pergunta definir um tempo mínimo de espera para as respostas.. Mas como o AP vai definir isso? sendo que ele muito provavelmente está enfrentando um problema e não sabe de antemão se a resposta é simples ou complexa?