# Identificação de Fonte/Referência automática

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

## Surgimento da ideia

Recentemente eu estava analisando uma [pergunta que havia feito aqui no MSOPT](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/890/3082) há algum tempo, sobre Oportunismo e notei que era um problema não conseguir identificar se o usuário leu ou não/copiou ou não uma fonte de informação citada por outro usuário, seja por comentário ou outra resposta, quem sabe até em outra pergunta, até, e estava indagando sobre.

E aí me surgiu esta ideia, utilizando algum meio, identificar automaticamente(obrigatoriamente) fontes/referência do autor de acordo, caso a resposta foi influenciada diretamente(via cópia direta) ou indiretamente (acessou o mesmo link via comentário).

## Por que não?

Não vejo porque não seria cabível uma implementação que traria benefícios para a comunidade, pois uma referência é importante, e todos nós sabemos disso.

## E como isso iria funcionar?

Exatamente, não sei dizer. Mas pelo que estive pensando, há alguns pontos que poderiam ser checados para a realização desta funcionalidade(quem sabe eu possa estar errado):

1. Checar se o usuário realizou um <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (Copy) em algum comentário/resposta de outro usuário aqui do SO.
2. Checar se o usuário acessou algum link relacionado à resposta, disponibilizado por algum outro usuário daqui do SO, seja na própria pergunta ou não.
3. Adicionar ao rodapé da resposta postada pelo autor que cometeu o **item 1** ou **item 2** as fontes sobre o autor do qual este usuário copiou ou utilizou o link referenciado por ele.

### Observações importantes

Estou apenas indagando sobre a funcionalidade, pois não sei como isto tudo poderia funcionar então claro, esta ideia poderia ser melhor pensada em questões de funcionamento, pelo pessoal daqui ou pelo pessoal do SO.

Claro que deve ser bem discutido o método a ser implementado, pois pode haver controvérsias, como por exemplo o usuário copiar algo do comentário por acidente ou para outra finalidade e depois escrever uma resposta contendo partes do texto copiados, claro que tudo deveria ser corretamente tratado e averiguado caso seja possível desenvolver um algoritmo que consiga prever todo tipo de controvérsia, ou 99% delas suficientemente bom para melhorar o site, e talvez uma possibilidade de editar esta informação caso entre em controvérsia.

## Resultado:

Desta forma, nenhum usuário seria mais chamado de **Oportunista** ou em alguns casos piores, **Ladrão**, e mesmo que não seja, as fontes e referências que são de suma importância sempre estariam presentes nas respostas, e vejo que isso traria uma qualidade imensa para o site.

## Exemplos:

Por exemplo, temos uma pergunta `x`, e temos uma resposta para a pergunta `x`, e 30segundos depois uma resposta `y` para a pergunta `x` foi postada. Digamos que:

> **Resposta x:** É só utilizar a função `window.open()` que você não terá mais problema.
>
> **Resposta y:** Para resolver este seu problema utilize a função `window.open()` ao invés de `showModalDialog()` pelo fato que ela está depreciada.

Neste caso, digamos que o algoritmo buscou por semelhanças e não encontrou, pois, em respostas pequenas e diretas o algoritmo seria mais "exigente" digamos assim e busca em respostas pequenas e diretas de forma mais exata, diferente de quando temos uma resposta maior onde o algoritmo iria checar de forma menos exata.

### Agora vamos inverter:

> **Resposta x:** Funções depreciadas são funções que atualmente não estão mais sendo usadas pois foram feitas funções melhores para realizar o mesmo feitio. Por isso se você substituir o `window.showModalDialog()` por `window.open()` seu problema irá sumir, pelo fato da `window.open()` não estar depreciada e realiza comportamento similar.
>
> **Resposta y:** Seu problema é que ela é uma função depreciada, então você deve utilizar `window.open()` no lugar da `window.showModalDialog()` para resolver seu problema, as funções depreciadas são funções que não estão mais sendo usadas pelo navegador, pois há outras que podem suprir a funcionalidade de forma parecida.

Neste caso o algoritmo deveria citar `y` como cópia/referência de resposta `x` pois o conteúdo é o mesmo e agrega o mesmo conhecimento, pelo fato de estar sendo utilizadas as mesmas palavras só que em ordem diferente e com algumas outras palavras envolvidas porém de maioria destas palavras sejam sinônimos.

**Ps: Gostaria de discutir acerca disto e averiguar com vocês, pois esta ideia pode trazer um benefício para o site.**

Comment: Funcionar automaticamente é uma péssima ideia. Afinal alguém pode perfeitamente ter clicado em todos os links da página e ainda assim vir com uma resposta original (se concluir que o conteúdo dos links estava errado, por exemplo). Da mesma forma um ctrl+c em um comentário pode vir meramente para citar o conteúdo. Se é alguém mau intencionado, isso é muito fácil de burlar. Se é bem intencionado, já vai citar a referência e não faz sentido. Quanto a métodos não automáticos, não vejo ganho, a final quem quiser por referência já vai por no corpo da postagem, não é necessário ter um novo campo.

Comment: Discordo @GuilhermeBernal Me desculpe mas não há nenhuma maneira possível para burlar uma coisa dessa se for bem feita. E se você leu toda a minha pergunta vai notar que eu falei que tem que ser feito tratamento no algoritmo pra prever essas coisas que você falou, afinal o computador tem inteligência artificial em sí, se você fizer um algoritmo inteligente.

Comment: O que impede alguém de ler um conteúdo de outra pessoa e digitar a mesma ideia com palavras diferentes?

Comment: Ou de não ler e digitar a mesma ideia com palavras parecidas?

Comment: Primeiramente, ler o conteúdo de alguém com atenção te faz absorver o conhecimento do tal. Se você escreveu com palavras diferentes você deu uma resposta da sua forma, e isso todos sabem que é permitido, cada um responde da maneira que achar que ficou melhor e a melhor resposta obterá mais votos positivos. Por isso, claramente, o algoritmo não iria implicar com isto.

Segundo, que, seria impossível ou extremamente improvável, alguém digitar exatamente a mesma coisa que outra pessoa na mesma pergunta sem ter lido a resposta, a não ser código ou textos muito pequenos.

Comment: E para complementar, qual o problema se essa funcionalidade não conseguisse tratar essa parte de "não ler e digitar a mesma ideia" ? afinal eu não veria problema nenhum em ter ali escrito na minha resposta referência da resposta acima sendo que o cara foi mais rápido que eu e teve o mesmo raciocínio. Até porque eu deletaria a minha resposta porque duas respostas iguais seria totalmente ruim para o site. E como eu disse, mesma resposta com palavras diferentes é comum acontecer e é benéfico, pois a melhor explicação seria a mais bem votada como eu disse.

Comment: Vocês estão citando os "raros" casos em que isso não seria 100% perfeitamente funcional. Só que vocês não sabem como isso REALMENTE iria funcionar, nem eu. Então gostaria de propor a vocês pensar no que isso traria de bom para a comunidade, em contrapé com estes "defeitos" que vocês estão citando e vejam se isso valeria a pena, coloquem na balança e vejam como isso poderia ser mais positivo do que negativo, apesar de que, eu achar que de nenhum modo isso poderia ser negativo...

Comment: Detectar Ctrl+C ou clique em links vai dar um monte de falsos positivos. Fazer um google no background para buscar *matches* é inviável também. Acho que é o tipo de coisa para humanos detectarem. Pode ser que alguém consiga postar conteúdo plagiado sem ser detectado por um bom tempo, mas eventualmente acaba descoberto. E se a magnitude do plágio é grande, provavelmente vai tomar uma suspensão bem comprida.

Comment: Mas você já tentou pensar na quantidade de respostas em que irá acertar, comparada com as que ele vai "errar" sendo que o erro na minha opinião não seria um erro mesmo e sim um alerta que sua resposta contem trechos iguais a outra resposta, e fazer o cara pensar se realmente vale a pena deixar duas questões bem parecidas na mesma pergunta. Eu por exemplo, excluiria a minha resposta caso ela estivesse igual a outra.

Comment: E outra coisa, algo que nunca gostei é que a mania do pessoal do Meta é de discordar de tudo e sempre falar da parte que pode ser considerado "ruim" e nunca comentar sobre o positivo que isso poderia causar, e comparar com o negativo que eventualmente ocorreria. Não sei se é só daqui ou se é um comportamento normal do ser humano mas pra discordar e ter comentários contra a maioria já apoia, mas pra ajudar e ver a parte boa do negócio ninguém tá ai.

Comment: Eu não estou contestando a proposta da ferramenta, estou contestando que o problema seja grave o suficiente para merecer a criação dessa ferramenta. Em muitos casos, dá pra resolver simplesmente dialogando com o autor do suposto plágio. Você vê isso acontecendo com que frequência? Pode incluir exemplos na sua pergunta?

Comment: Uai, o fundamento da sua proposta é `1` e `2` e acho que os dois não tem base. Poderia propor algo positivo e alternativo, mas não acho necessário... O ônus de fundamentar o [meta-tag:novo-recurso] é seu, e se acha que não deve alterar nada na pergunta baseado no *feedback* aqui nos comentários, ok...

Comment: é que eu só vejo feedback negativo, confesso que isso me deixa um pouco intrigado a partir do meu ponto de vista. mas em relação aos problemas que vocês falaram, eu gostaria novamente de falar que a ideia que eu dei é a base, e quero só a ajuda pra formular isso melhor para que ela se adapte de uma forma que funcione 100% entendem? não é que eu já esteja especificando como exatamente vai funcionar mas o que vale é a ideia, e vocês não acham que esta ideia pode vir a se tornar uma funcionalidade benéfica?

Comment: Normalmente, uma solução técnica só vai ser considerada se for para enfrentar um problema endêmico... vide último comentário do bfavaretto. . . . . [ps] `só vejo feedback negativo` ---> *links or didn't happen* :)

Comment: No meu ponto de vista, algo que pode acrescentar uma qualidade ao site, mesmo que não haja muitos casos deste problema, é valido, pois melhora o site, e toda melhoria na minha opinião é bem vinda, mesmo que demore e de trabalho para fazer, pois é de pouco em pouco que se constrói algo bom, sabe.

Comment: -1 por não editar a pergunta para elucidar todos os problemas levantados aqui nos comentários :/

Comment: @brasofilo Você realmente não entendeu nada da minha proposta. Pois eu não sou o programador do SO, e não sei dizer como isto será feito mas a ideia seria isso que eu falei porém com todos os problemas que você disse, tratados de forma correta para que não acontecam/acontecam com minúscula frequência, Entende? eu não estou apresentando um projeto de desenvolvimento e sim uma ideia, portanto os levantamentos dos comentários não são um problema na minha proposta em sí.

Comment: Antigamente no início do SOPT era uma maravilha, você postava uma ideia e todos vinham comentar sobre como ela poderia ser útil, e surgiam dicas de melhoria, surgiam críticas construtivas, e meios de melhorar a proposta em si, hoje em dia pelo que vejo, tem muita gente pra falar que a proposta não tem como ser feita e que não deve ser considerada porque não tem base, porque não é necessário, porque haverá controvérsias, além de levar a minha ideia a nível de implementação como se eu tivesse expondo um projeto de desenvolvimento, infelizmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto bom você fala de merecimento, quer dizer então que uma ideia que contribua por mais que seja 0,01% apenas significa que ela não é boa o "suficiente" para merecer ser feita? Pra mim melhoria é melhoria, se irá melhorar de verdade, deve ser feito, nem que seja uma melhoria minúscula.

Comment: Minha opinião sobre a ideia: 1. A quantidade de falsos positivos desse tipo de detecção automática seria massiva. 2. O problema que ela enfrenta não é tão grande assim e está muito abaixo da nossa capacidade de resolver manualmente (não vejo plágio toda semana). 3. Possui implementação não trivial (tem que se provar valer muito a pena para ser posto em prática).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Se você for programador poderia entender que a quantidade de falsos positivos não seria tão grande como você acha, dependendo do algoritmo de identificação, pois existe inteligência artificial para isto.

Comment: @brasofilo quer dizer que agora são todas inúteis a não ser que sejam extremamente boas?

Comment: @PauloRoberto os métodos que apresentou acima causariam bastantes falsos positivos. Pode mostrar que métodos seriam esses que fariam a detecção ser boa? Eu não vejo como.

Comment: Ok, vou concordar com vocês, editei a pergunta e coloquei exemplos, conforme solicitado aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Eu só quis dizer que, na minha opinião, há outras prioridades. Desculpe, mas eu não enxergo um problema real que você queira consertar. Mas toda ideia pode sim ser válida, e não sou eu quem decide o que vai ser implementado ou não. Só acho que quanto mais sólida for a sua justificativa, mais chance você tem de levarem sua ideia adiante. Por isso questionei a justificativa, nem estou preocupado com a implementação neste momento.

Comment: Eu realmente ficaria *ofendido* se o sistema sugerisse que alguma resposta minha foi uma cópia de outra. Entretanto não estou me importando se alguém copiar minha resposta. Acho que o resultado seria mais negativo que positivo.

Comment: ok foi só uma ideia mas já entendi que todos odiaram '-'

Comment: @PauloRoberto - _odiaram_  é uma palavra um tanto quanto forte, não?  Eu diria que sua ideia é válida, mas, no momento não existem casos suficientes que necessitem de implementar tal ferramenta. Talvez, daqui a alguns anos isso seja necessário, mas no momento não é.

Comment: Pois é, eu não odiei nada. Você apresentou uma idéia, foi rebatida e não teve contra-argumentos para convencer. *The end*. Sem ressentimentos, nobre senador :P

Comment: Salve, @Paulo :) Encontrei uma resposta do Shog9 que tem o tutorial definitivo de como fazer uma `[feature-request]`: [***Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1287812). Lembrei de você na hora, inclusive porque participei na negativação daqueles 3 posts seus lá no Metão que tomaram uma saraivada de -1.

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente, um novo recurso deve ser para solucionar algum problema ou melhorar o funcionamento de alguma parte do site.

O AP não apresenta nenhuma evidência de que plágio seja um problema endêmico (ou mesmo localizado) no site e que as ferramentas humanas não sejam capazes de cuidar dos eventuais casos descobertos.

Acho interessante que no Stack Overflow que recebe uma avalanche de [8 mil perguntas e ~16 mil respostas diárias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201652/185667), isso nunca foi motivo de uma *feature-request* semelhante:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism+feature-request
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism+feature-request

Claro que isso não serve como justificativa para dizer que a detecção automática não é uma boa idéia, mas se isso não é um problema lá onde é humanamente impossível verificar todo o conteúdo postado, porque seria um problema aqui? Para quê gastar tempo de desenvolvimento com um problema que não existe?

**Relacionado**:

- [Plagiarism is a good way to earn reputation. Combatting this after the fact?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237712/185667)

**Caça plágio**:
Se alguém tiver interesse, acho que pode adaptar esta query para investigar se o problema existe de fato:

- [Exact duplicate answers per user - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/198440/exact-duplicate-answers-per-user)

Comment: E por favor, quando encontrar casos de alguém chamando alguém de "oportunista" e/ou "ladrão", sinalize imediatamente para intervenção dos moderadores.